# How to execute arbitrary SQL statement in ASP.NET/Angular application

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, sql-server

I am trying to make a trivial call to a SQL Server 2000 database using Angular's `$http` service. Angular factory containing the `$http`:

```
var RegistrationFactory = function ($http, $q, SessionService) {
    return function (email, password, confirmPassword) {
        var result = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: SessionService.apiUrl + '/api/Account/Register',
            data: { Email: email, Password: password, ConfirmPassword: confirmPassword },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
        .success(function (response) {
            result.resolve(response);
        })
        .error(function (response) {
            result.reject(response);
        });

        return result.promise;
    }
}

RegistrationFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'SessionService'];
```

And inside the `AccountController`:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<bool> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {

            string queryString = "INSERT INTO Northwind VALUES('test', 'values')";
            SqlConnection cnxn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TheConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, cnxn);
            cnxn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnxn.Close();

            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email, 
                Email = model.Email
            };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return false;
            }
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, false);
            return true;
        }
```

This program is merely trying to show that the SQL-related codes are executed upon the `RegistrationFactory` being utilized.
The `Register.cshtml` view:

```
<form ng-submit="register()">
    <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
    <input id="emailAddress" type="text" ng-model="registerForm.emailAddress" required />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="registerForm.password" required />

    <label for="confirmPassword">Password:</label>
    <input id="confirmPassword" type="password" ng-model="registerForm.confirmPassword" required />


    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

And the `RegisterController.js` that handles above view:

```
var RegisterController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.registerForm = {
        emailAddress: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
        registrationFailure: false
    };


    $scope.register = function () {
        var result = RegistrationFactory($scope.registerForm.emailAddress, $scope.registerForm.password, $scope.registerForm.confirmPassword);
        result.then(function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $location.path('/routeOne');
            } else {
                $scope.registerForm.registrationFailure = true;
            }
        });
    }
}

RegisterController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'RegistrationFactory'];
```

I am trying to figure out how to actually execute the statement as the result of my `$http`. Additionally, being able to pass data through the `'POST'` would be awesome. And, yes, it has to be for SQL Server 2000, so Entity Framework is not an option. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: So what is your question/problem, where are you stuck? Also you ADO.NET needs improvement although I realize its just to see if everything works, you are not using parameters: you are not using `using` blocks for your connection, `Northwind` is database and not a table so that insert will fail -  just to name a couple of issues. See this [SO Documents doc for ADO.NET and best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements#t=201607271659282767349) which has an insert example.

Comment: When I run my program in Visual Studio and click the "Register" button, I am properly routed to `routeOne`, which seems to indicate that the `RegistrationFactory` is reached, but no entry is inserted into the database, meaning the `Register` method in the `AccountController` is never reached. So the main issue is executing a query on my database through the API.

Comment: That is a very odd way of checking if your code is reached. Why not just set a break point instead? If you do not have VS on the server then use remote debugging or WinDbg.

Comment: Will do! I'm new to the VS environment and integrating programs in this manner. Thank you, I am sure it will be educational!